# How to animate bottom: value to bottom: auto

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to create a menu that is hidden off screen on the top of the document. There is a little portion showing that will be hoverable which will bring the rest of the menu into view. Trying to animate bottom to auto but it isn't working. Was wondering if someone knows how or better way to create a menu off screen similar to my codepen.

http://codepen.io/anthony-dandrea/pen/EjqYqj

`.hud` is the class that's giving me the animation problem.

```
.hud {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
  bottom: calc(100% - 39px);
}
.hud:hover {
  bottom: 80%;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

Comment: You can't animate to or from 'auto' with purely CSS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already mentioned by Patrick Allen in comments, you cannot animate/transition from or to an "auto" value using CSS. For your case, you could replace it with `transform: translate()` like in the below snippet and achieve the same effect.

Below is the relevant SCSS code and what it does:

- The `transform: translateY(-100%)` moves the elements content upwards by the exact height of the container element. This would hide the whole container.
- A `top: 39px` is added such that the chevron icon is still shown and only the content is hidden.
- On hover the `transform` is nullified by doing `transform: translateY(0%)`. This puts the element back in its original position.
- But because of the `top: 39px` present in the unhovered state, the position of the container would be offset a bit and that can be nullified by adding `top: 0px` on hover.

```
.hud {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s;
  top: 39px;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  &:hover {
     top: 0px;
     transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #121111;
}
.hud {
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  top: 39px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
.hud:hover {
  top: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
  transform: translateY(0%);
}
.pull-down {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.pull-down:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.hud:hover .pull-down {
  color: #fff;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="hud">
  <div class="hud-internal">
    <p>foobar</p>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-down" data-hud-toggle></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#click').click(function () {

    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var lineHeight = $('#line').height();
    var desiredBottom = 100;

    var newPosition = windowHeight - (lineHeight + desiredBottom);

    $('#line').animate({top:newPosition},1000,function () {
        $('#line').css({
            bottom: desiredBottom,
            bottom: 'auto'
        });
    });

});
```

Here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gxkuS/487/)

Answer (score 0):

Give `top: 0;` to `.hud` element and it will work fine. Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpOKdE